# SqlBulkCopy Unicode/UTF8 error

Tags: c#, special-characters, sqlbulkcopy, nvarchar

I am using c# SqlBulkCopy functionality to save records with UTF8 encoded multilingual values. My database field is 'NVARCHAR(max)' and my to be saved value is 我多言語で我. But it is saving as '???????' . Is there any way to save this exact Japanese/Multilingual value via `SqlBulkCopy`.

```
row["ParameterValue"] = RegData.ParamValue;
```

I debugged & checked the above line also. But data is coming to above line also totally fine. After this line i am executing

```
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
```

(I have tried this with simple db insert & its working fine. but i have millions records to be saved at once. so simple db insert is not good for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'`???????`' is the result I'd expect from:

```
select cast(N'我多言語で我' as varchar(max))
```

Inserting to a `NVARCHAR` column via a newly created `DataTable` with a `string` column seems to work for me...

If you run a SQL profiler trace you should see an `insert bulk ...` statement with the datatype being used for the bulk dataset (n.b. you won't see the values).

If this and the target field are the correct `NVARCHAR` type, maybe there's some server side processing occuring?

Edit: the following works for me

```
    // insert code to create SqlConnection
    var dbName = string.Format("Test{0}", Environment.TickCount);
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = string.Format("create database {0}", dbName);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.CommandText = string.Format("use {0}", dbName);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    try
    {
        command.CommandText = "create table Test (Value nvarchar(max))";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

        var row = dataTable.NewRow();
        row["Value"] = "我多言語で我";
        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

        var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Test";
        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);

        Console.WriteLine("Please check the following query:");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("select * from {0}..Test", dbName));
        Console.ReadKey();                
    }
    finally
    {
        command.CommandText = string.Format("drop database {0}", dbName);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Thankz for your comment Peter. But i have used nvarchar. it works fine for nvarchar. Also as i have see all the server side processing & all are fine

Comment: I've added the example code I used. AFAIK if you are setting the correct unicode into the dataTable row and the target column is `NVARCHAR`, the trace looks correct and with no triggers/views involved, there isn't much that could go wrong...

Comment: This is exactly what I just overlooked. I had neglected to use `NVARCHAR` types in the database, and was trying to figure out why `SqlBulkCopy` was not working with the unicode data, when it was actually my own error.

Comment: Just use nvarchar as your destination column type. It should solve the problem